# iPhone + Messages Beta: prevent iPhone from vibrating for every message?

Tags: messages, notifications

I'm using the [Messages Beta](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/messages-beta/) on Lion to receive iMessages on my MacBook Pro. I also have my iPhone set up with my iMessage account.

When I receive a message, it's delivered on both devices. If I read the message on my computer, it disappears from the lock screen of my iPhone, so it doesn't fill up during a conversation.

But, this doesn't prevent my iPhone from vibrating *every time* I receive a message — and if I'm having an extended rapid-fire iMessage conversation with someone using my computer, this can get annoying. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, this seems to be more of a timing issue, and I think Apple has improved the system overall. Basically, it's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that's not possible in the current iOS.

But there are a few work-arounds:

- You can define a [specific vibrating tone for that specific contact](http://www.pcworld.com/article/242238/how_to_use_custom_vibrations_in_ios_5.html) person which will do almost nothing (unlike the default long and hard vibrating)
- or you can disable vibrating when you enter Silent Mode and when you start having this rapid-fire conversation, just switch your iPhone to silent mode and no vibrating will happen!

Comment: I figured this would be the answer... thanks for the alternatives, though!